# Node.js - Limiting the number of requests I make

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, async.js

I have a Node app in which there is a Gremlin client:

```
var Gremlin = require('gremlin');

const client = Gremlin.createClient(
    443,
    config.endpoint,
    {
        "session": false,
        "ssl": true,
        "user": `/dbs/${config.database}/colls/${config.collection}`,
        "password": config.primaryKey
    }
);
```

With which I then making calls to a CosmoDB to add some records using:

```
async.forEach(pData, function (data, innercallback) {
    if (data.type == 'Full'){
      client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + data.$.id + "\")", {}, innercallback);
    } else {
        innercallback(null);
    }
}, outercallback);
```

However on my Azure side there is a limit of 400 requests / second and subsequently I get the error:

```
ExceptionType : RequestRateTooLargeException
ExceptionMessage : Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can restrict the number of requests made per second, without having to scale up on Azure (as that costs more :) )

Additionally:

I tried using

```
async.forEachLimit(pData, 400, function (data, innercallback) {
    if (data.type == 'Full'){
      client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + data.$.id + "\")", {}, innercallback);
    } else {
        innercallback(null);
    }
}, outercallback);
```

However if keep seeing `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` if its too high otherwise if I reduce I just get the same request rate too large exception.

Thanks.

Comment: `forEachLimit` should do the job, can you post a sample of its usage? `async.forEachLimit(pData, function (data, 400 innercallback) {` obviously has a typo.

Comment: @SergeyLapin - have updated code above, I only added the `forEachLimit` and a number parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

That might happen because `innercallback` is called synchronously in `else` case. It should be:

```
} else {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        innercallback(null)
    });
}
```

The call to `forEachLimit` looks generally correct, but you need to make sure that when a request is really fired (`if` block), `innercallback` is not called earlier than 1 second to guarantee that there are no more than 400 request in one second fired. The easiest is to delay the callback execution exactly for 1 second:

```
client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + data.$.id + "\")", {},
function(err) {
    setTimeout(function() { innercallback(err); }, 1000);
});
```

The more accurate solution would be to calculate the actual request+response time and `setTimeout` only for the time remaining to 1 second.

As a further improvement, looks like you can filter your `pData` array before doing async stuff to get rid of `if...else`, so eventually:

```
var pDataFull = pData.filter(function(data) => {
    return data.type == 'Full';
});

async.forEachLimit(pDataFull, 400, function (data, innercallback) {
    client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + data.$.id + 
        "\")", {},
        function(err) {
            setTimeout(function() { innercallback(err); }, 1000);
        }
    );
}, outercallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear up something first. You don't have a 400 requests/second collection but a 400 RU/s collection. RUs stand for request units and they don't translate to a request.

Roughly:

- A retrieval request for the retrieval of a document that's 1KB will cost 1 RU.
- A modification for the retrieval of a document that's 1KB will cost 5 RU.

Assuming your documents are 1KB big, you can only add 80 documents per second.

Now that we have that out of the way, it sounds like [async.queue()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) can do the trick for you.

Comment: Ah ok, understood the RU. However don't see how I would use async.queue - would I replace the function in my for loop as per the example in the link?

Comment: Yeah you would add your code in the callback and set the concurrency for your requests.